# Ansible execute command locally and then on remote server

Tags: ansible, ipmitool

I am trying to start a server using ansible shell module with **ipmitools** and then do configuration change on that server once its up.

Server with ansible installed also has ipmitools.

On server with ansible i need to execute ipmitools to start target server and then execute playbooks on it.

Is there a way to execute local ipmi commands on server running ansible to start target server through ansible and then execute all playbooks over ssh on target server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run any command locally by providing the `delegate_to` parameter.

```
- shell: ipmitools ...
  delegate_to: localhost
```

If ansible complains about connecting to `localhost` via ssh, you need to add an entry in your inventory like this:

```
localhost              ansible_connection=local
```

or in `host_vars/localhost`:

```
ansible_connection: local
```

See [behavioral parameters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters).

Next, you're going to need to wait until the server is booted and accessible though ssh. [Here](https://support.ansible.com/hc/en-us/articles/201958037-Reboot-a-server-and-wait-for-it-to-come-back) is an article from Ansible covering this topic and this is the task they have listed:

```
- name: Wait for Server to Restart
  local_action:
    wait_for
    host={{ inventory_hostname }}
    port=22
    delay=15
    timeout=300
  sudo: false
```

If that doesn't work (since it is an older article and I think I previously had issues with this solution) you can look into the answers of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877781/how-to-wait-for-server-restart-using-ansible).

Comment: thanks @udondan its almost working except that with wait_for module i want to loop over "host={{item.ipaddress}}" or "host=[webservers]" is it possible?? https://paste.fedoraproject.org/250894/14385919/
but returns "One or more undefined variables: 'item' is undefined"

Comment: sorry my bad i missed with_items: thanks now its working :)