# Order of notify handlers

Tags: ansible

I have a task:

```
- name: uploads docker configuration file
  template:
    src: 'docker.systemd.j2'
    dest: '/etc/systemd/system/docker.service'
  notify:
    - daemon reload
    - restart docker
```

in Ansible playbook's [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html), there is a sentence:

> Notify handlers are always run in the order written.

So, it is expected, that **daemon reload** will be ran before **restart docker**, but in logs, i have:

```
TASK [swarm/docker : uploads docker configuration file] ************************
…
NOTIFIED HANDLER daemon reload
NOTIFIED HANDLER restart docker
…
RUNNING HANDLER [swarm/docker : restart docker] ********************************
…
RUNNING HANDLER [swarm/docker : daemon reload] *********************************
…
```

There are no more "NOTIFIED HANDLER" in logs. Can anyone explain, what i'm doing wrong? :(

Comment: Looks like the documentation has been updated: "Notify handlers are always run in the same order they are defined, not in the order listed in the notify statement."

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I think you may have “restart docker” listed before “daemon reload” in your handlers file.

That part of the ansible documentation is a bit misleading. It means that handlers are executed *in the order they are written in the handlers file*, not the order they are notified.

This is little more clear in [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#controlling-when-handlers-run):

> Handlers always run in the order they are defined, not in the order listed in the notify-statement. This is also the case for handlers using listen.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you are working with multiple roles and you do an `include_role` task, it counts all of that role's handlers as being defined later than everything else to that point. I am not sure about whether `import_role` task has a different behavior here, but I am 99% certain that if you just list your roles in the `roles` section of your playbook, the handler definition order will match the order you listed your roles out.

Answer (score 9):

I just figured out that I can have handlers call other handlers.

Example task:

```
- name: Configure Apache
  copy: src=apache-azkaban.conf dest=/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/azkaban.conf
  notify:
   - a2enmod proxy
   - a2enmod proxy_http
```

In my `handlers/main.yml`:

```
- name: a2enmod proxy
  shell: a2enmod proxy
  notify:
    - restart apache2

- name: a2enmod proxy_http
  shell: a2enmod proxy_http
  notify:
    - restart apache2

- name: restart apache2
  service: name=apache2 state=restarted
```