# Have ansible playbook wait until host is active

Tags: ansible

I am looking to run a playbook that checks if a host is active, and if not check again in 24 hours.

```
start playbook

    do while host X is not up
    {
        wait 24 hours
    }
```

Is this possible in ansible? From the docs, it's very unclear if it is.

Comment: possibly a common and duplicated question https://stackoverflow.com/a/23888382/338011 need clarification and code.

Comment: Yes its possible, If it is unclear, Please let us know what you have tried so far and where you got stuck?

Comment: Why would you have a playbook run for 24hrs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ansible's [`wait_for`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/wait_for_module.html) module.

```
- name: Wait for host
  wait_for:
    host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    port: 22
    sleep: 86400     # check every 24 hours
    timeout: 604800  # exit after 7 days
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: In case you are not waiting for a reboot, but the initial boot, the parameter `gather_facts: no` is helpful. This should be set on the same indentation level as `wait_for`, but even better would be `wait_for_connection`. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_connection_module.html